# Norm of inverse of all one matrix plus a PSD matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-norms

Consider the operator norm of the following $n \times n$ matrix:

$$
\|(I + 11^* + X^*X)^{-1} 11^* (I + 11^* + X^*X)^{-1}\|,
$$
where X is a $n \times n$ matrix.

Is it bounded by $\frac{1}{n}$?

I know it is true without the matrix $X^*X$, but how to deal with the matrix $X^*X$?

Comment: Which matrix norm?

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri Sorry, the operator norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reformulation of the problem. Let $P=I+XX^\ast$ and $y=P^{-1}e$. By Sherman-Morrison formula,
$$
x:=(I+XX^\ast+ee^T)^{-1}e
=(I+ye^T)^{-1}y
=\left(I-\frac{ye^T}{1+e^Ty}\right)y
=\frac{y}{1+e^Ty}=\frac{P^{-1}e}{1+e^TP^{-1}e}.
$$
By a change of orthonormal basis, the expression on the RHS can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{Dv}{1+v^\ast Dv}
$$
where $\|v\|=\|e\|=\sqrt{n}$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$ with $0<d_i\le1$ for each $i$ (the $d_i$s are the eigenvalues of $P^{-1}$). The problem thus reduces to showing that
$$
\|xx^\ast\|=\|x\|^2=\left\|\frac{Dv}{1+v^\ast Dv}\right\|^2
=\frac{\sum_id_i^2|v_i|^2}{\left(1+\sum_id_i|v_i|^2\right)^2}
$$
is bounded above by $\frac1n$ when $\|v\|=\sqrt{n}$ and $0<d_i\le1$ for each $i$.

Comment: How do you get the first inequality?

Comment: Thanks for your idea!